# How do I set TTL for oneshot search in Splunk API using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, splunk, splunk-sdk

I am intermittently getting the following error back from the Splunk API (about 40% of the time search works as expected):

> HTTP 503 Service Unavailable -- Search not executed: This search could
> not be dispatched because the role-based disk usage quota of search
> artifacts for user "[REDACTED]" has been reached (usage=1067MB,
> quota=1000MB). Use the [[/app/search/job_manager|Job Manager]] to
> delete some of your search artifacts, or ask your Splunk administrator
> to increase the disk quota of search artifacts for your role in
> authorize.conf., usage=1067MB, quota=1000MB, user=[REDACTED],
> concurrency_category="historical",
> concurrency_context="user_instance-wide"

The default ttl for a search in the splunk api is 10 min (at least for my company). I am told I need to lower the TTL for my searches (which are massive) and I will stop running out of space.  I do not have admin access, so no ability to increase my space or clear space on the fly (as far I know).  I can find code on how to lower TTL using saved searches, but I use oneshot searches.  It is not reasonable for me to switch.

How do I lower ttl for oneshot searches?
Here is what I have now that does not seem to lower TTL:

```
#setup splunk connection
service = client.connect(
    host=HOST,
    port=PORT,
    username=suser,
    password=spass,
    autologin=True,
    )
#setup arguments
kwargs_oneshot = {"count" :  "0",
                  "earliest_time": begin,
                  "latest_time": end,
                  "set_ttl":60
                 }
#setup search job    
oneshotsearch_results = service.jobs.oneshot(query, **kwargs_oneshot)
# Get the results and display them using the ResultsReader
reader = results.ResultsReader(oneshotsearch_results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `set_ttl`, I believe you need `ttl` or `timeout`.  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTREF/RESTsearch#search.2Fjobs

Also, consider making your searches less massive or running them less often.